# How do you move software input panel (keyboard) to bottom of windows mobile screen?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pinvoke

I'm trying to move the keyboard to the bottom of the screen to hide the 35px menu bar that it shows by default on windows mobile 5/6.  All of the examples I've seen about modifying the menu bar deal with hiding the button "MS_SIPBUTTON". The two parts of my question are:

How can I move the keyboard down 35 pixels on the screen?

And, where is "MS_SIPBUTTON" defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part one:

The best way I could muster to move the keyboard was a collection of Windows API calls all referenced from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net)

First a bunch of DllImport statements:

```
        [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string caption, string className);

        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        internal static extern void MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        extern static int SipShowIM(int dwFlag);
```

Next some constants and variables:

```
        Rectangle sipbutton;
        Rectangle keyboardBackground;
        Rectangle keyboard;

        private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private const int SW_SHOW = 1;
        private const int GW_CHILD = 5;
        private const int SIPF_ON = 1;
        private const int SIPF_OFF = 0;
```

Functions for showing and hiding the SIP button that displays at the bottom of the page.  They are called in my constructor and destructor

```
            public void HideSip()
            {
                IntPtr hTaskBarWindow = FindWindow("MS_SIPBUTTON", null);
                if (hTaskBarWindow != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    RECT rct;

                    if (!GetWindowRect(hTaskBarWindow, out rct))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                        return;
                    }

                    Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();

                    myRect.X = (int)rct.Left;
                    myRect.Y = (int)rct.Top;
                    myRect.Width = (int)(rct.Right - rct.Left + 1);
                    myRect.Height = (int)(rct.Bottom - rct.Top + 1);

                    //save previous state
                    sipbutton = myRect;

                    MoveWindow(hTaskBarWindow, myRect.X, myRect.Y + 1000, myRect.Width, myRect.Height, true);
                    //MoveWindow(hTaskBarWindow, 100, 100, 100, 100, true);
                }
            }

            public void RestoreSip()
            {
                IntPtr hTaskBarWindow = FindWindow("MS_SIPBUTTON", null);
                if (hTaskBarWindow != IntPtr.Zero && sipbutton.Height > 0 && sipbutton.Width > 0)
                {
                    MoveWindow(hTaskBarWindow, sipbutton.X, sipbutton.Y, sipbutton.Width, sipbutton.Height, true);
                }
            }
```

With that out of the way we need to move the keyboard down to the bottom of the screen:

```
public void MoveKeyboardDown(int pixelsDown)
        {

            IntPtr hSipWindow = FindWindow("SipWndClass",null);
            if (hSipWindow != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                RECT rct;

                if (!GetWindowRect(hSipWindow, out rct))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                    return;
                }

                Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();

                myRect.X = (int)rct.Left;
                myRect.Y = (int)rct.Top;
                myRect.Width = (int)(rct.Right - rct.Left + 1);
                myRect.Height = (int)(rct.Bottom - rct.Top + 1);

                //save previous state
                keyboard = myRect;

                MoveWindow(hSipWindow, myRect.X, myRect.Y + pixelsDown, myRect.Width, myRect.Height, true);

            }

            IntPtr hSipWindow2 = FindWindow("SipBackDropWndClass",null);
            if (hSipWindow2 != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                RECT rct;

                if (!GetWindowRect(hSipWindow2, out rct))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                    return;
                }

                Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();

                myRect.X = (int)rct.Left;
                myRect.Y = (int)rct.Top;
                myRect.Width = (int)(rct.Right - rct.Left + 1);
                myRect.Height = (int)(rct.Bottom - rct.Top + 1);

                //save previous state
                keyboardBackground = myRect;

                MoveWindow(hSipWindow2, myRect.X, myRect.Y + pixelsDown, myRect.Width, myRect.Height, true);

            }


            arPages[iCurrentPage].Invalidate();
        }

        public void RestoreKeyboard()
        {

            IntPtr hSipWindow = FindWindow("SipWndClass", null);
            if (hSipWindow != IntPtr.Zero && keyboard.Height > 0 && keyboard.Width > 0)
            {
                MoveWindow(hSipWindow, keyboard.X, keyboard.Y, keyboard.Width, keyboard.Height, true);
            }

            IntPtr hSipWindow2 = FindWindow("SipBackDropWndClass", null);
            if (hSipWindow2 != IntPtr.Zero && keyboardBackground.Height > 0 && keyboardBackground.Width > 0)
            {
                MoveWindow(hSipWindow2, keyboardBackground.X, keyboardBackground.Y, keyboardBackground.Width, keyboardBackground.Height, true);
            }

        }
```

When you want to show the keyboard do some thing like this:

```
    SipShowIM(SIPF_ON);
    MoveKeyboardDown(25);
```

When you want to hide it do this:

```
    SipShowIM(SIPF_OFF);
    RestoreKeyboard();
```

Part two:

I was able to discover the names of windows referenced above using CE Remote Tools/Windows CE Remote Spy.  The executable is "ccspy.exe"

Comment: I'm finding that when I call SipShowIM(SIPF_OFF) I'm not seeing EnabledChanged isn't being fired which causes issues with my resize logic. Have you seen this behaviour?

Comment: @JLWarlow I haven't seen that behaviour. And as it turns out, I no longer have access to a windows mobile device to test it either.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a test project to GitHub that shows my problem in case anyone else has an idea : git://github.com/jlwarlow/SIPTest.git