# Unable to hide SIP menu bar when showing and re-hiding SIP

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a Windows Mobile 6 solution where I'm trying to hide the bottom bar. I have my own button to display the SIP (it's larger and easier for the user to click on than the standard one). This brings up the SIP fine and I'm using MoveWindow to move the keyboard down so that it's on the bottom of the screen:
[image: Image of SIP shown at bottom of screen]

However when I try to restore the window back when hiding the SIP the standard keyboard appears:
[image: Image of SIP keyboard that I don't want]

I'm using the code found elsewhere on stackoveflow: [How do you move software input panel (keyboard) to bottom of windows mobile screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153640/how-do-you-move-software-input-panel-keyboard-to-bottom-of-windows-mobile-scre) but can't get it fully working due to problem above.

Comment: Why do you move the SIP back into view as long as your app runs? That will bring back the SIP button. Better save the SIP button position and size, move it out and at end of app restore it. Or, even easier, define your Form as WindowState=Maximized.

Comment: I think what's happening is the SIP button is still appearing even though the keyboard has been moved (from the image above there is a small green line the same width as the SIP button in the bottom image.) When the SIP keyboard is then hidden, (SIP.Enabled = false), the SIP button is then visible. I had no luck getting rid of the blighter. Setting WindowState = Maximized doesn't hide the SIP button unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Finally cracked this. I needed to use SetWindowPos using SWP_NOACTIVATE and not MoveWindow. MoveWindow was somehow changing the enabled state of the SIP causing issues.

Comment: @josef You're welcome. I posted this as I've spend too many hours on search engines trying to find the answer. Hopefully if someone is having the same issue as me, this fixes if for them and saves a headache!